# turtlebot driver.launch error: object has no attribute Rotation

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When I try to launch the driver.launch file I get the following error.
'module' object has no attribute 'Rotation'
Any help would be appreciated.

Full output at launch is below.
The create beeps when I run driver.launch, so I know it has connectivity to the Create.
Thanks in advance for assistance.

Startup cut and paste:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

```
setting /run_id to d10a2cf8-fe46-11e0-bfa5-60eb695252d6
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2374]
started core service [/rosout]
process[turtlebot_node-2]: started with pid [2378]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1319464096.921957] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1319464096.922354] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1319464096.922668] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1319464096.922976] has gyro: True
Failed to contact device with error: ['module' object has no attribute 'Rotation']. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.[turtlebot_node-2] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/wilson/.ros/log/d10a2cf8-fe46-11e0-bfa5-60eb695252d6/turtlebot_node-2*.log
respawning...
[turtlebot_node-2] restarting process
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11658/turtlebot-driver.launch-error:-object-has-no-attribute-rotation/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-24**:
Please provide more information on what computer you're running, how you installed ROS and turtlebot software, what version you're running etc so we can try to understand or reproduce your problem.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support  My first guess is that you have not built all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reinstall of ROS electric after upgrade to Natty version of Ubuntu appears to have fixed the error.

---

Originally posted by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) with karma: 693 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0